# Is it possible to get the data from a range in an easy way in C#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have a range of 2 dates given by my business: "we would like to have all data from July and 6 previous months". I create two dates:

```
_range1.MaxDateTime = new DateTime(today. Year, 7, 31);
_range1.MinDateTime = rangeLastDate.AddMonths(-6).AddDays(1);
```

Because the system will always perform the calculation on last 6 months. Last date is also always end of month. I have no problem to get the last day of the month. C# has the feature `EndOfMonth()` for this. But when I do so I always get the last day at midnight. when I create the `DateTime()` myself I also get a date a midnight.

In my code I use Entity Framework with LinQ. (old EF, not Core yet)

```
_range1_ShippedQuantities = DbContext.Job_Dtl
    .Where(j=> j.LastShipDate >= _range1.MinDateTime && j.LastShipDate <= _range1.MaxDateTime)
```

This is not correct because my last datetime is the 31 at midnight and not the first of next month at midnight. I should do

```
_range1_ShippedQuantities = DbContext.Job_Dtl
    .Where(j=> j.LastShipDate.Date >= _range1.MinDateTime.Date && j.LastShipDate.Date <= _range1.MaxDateTime.Date)
```

Or I can also manipulate the dates do force the time at 23:59:59... what I don't like. I still miss 1 second. I can add 999 milliseconds but i will still tell you I miss one millisecond. I can also add one day in a temp variable and use this temp variable in my LinQ query... yes but I have the feeling there is something better. How do you deal with these ranges?

But LinQ does not allow this. LinQ for entities cannot recognize the date.

Comment: usually, to get information for some dates you'd use `date >= YYYY-MM-01 00:00:00 and date < YYYY2-MM2-01 00:00:00` so you will get absolutely all transactions even with 99999999999 nanoseconds

Comment: What's wrong with using `< new DateTime(2022, 8, 1)` instead of `<= new DateTime(2022, 7, 31, 23, 59, 59)`?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I'm just asking if there is something special for this in C#

Comment: @BastienVandamme - You could do `.AddTicks(-1)` on the first of the month to get the last possible `DateTime` for the previous month. Just use `<` on the first of the month - it's simpler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As several people have commented on your question, the simplest and most common way to solve this problem is to choose an *exclusive* end date rather than an *inclusive* one.

```
var minDateInclusive = rangeLastDate.AddMonths(-6).AddDays(1);
var maxDateExclusive = rangeLastDate.AddDays(1);
```

```
DbContext.Job_Dtl
    .Where(j=> j.LastShipDate >= minDateInclusive 
        && j.LastShipDate < maxDateExclusive);
```